# Adding location to Twitter sentiment analysis

Tags: python, twitter, nlp

I am trying to build a twitter sentiment analysis tool and want to add a geolocation - that looks for tweets within 10 miles of NYC. How do I do this? I I tried to add the location to the end of the url but it did not work.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib2 as urllib

# See assignment1.html instructions or README for how to get these credentials

api_key = ''
api_secret = ''
access_token_key = '
access_token_secret = ''

_debug = 0

oauth_token    = oauth.Token(key=access_token_key, secret=access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

http_method = "GET"


http_handler  = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)

'''
Construct, sign, and open a twitter request
using the hard-coded credentials above.
'''
def twitterreq(url, method, parameters):
  req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                             token=oauth_token,
                                             http_method=http_method,
                                             http_url=url, 
                                             parameters=parameters)

  req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)

  headers = req.to_header()

  if http_method == "POST":
    encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
  else:
    encoded_post_data = None
    url = req.to_url()

  opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
  opener.add_handler(http_handler)
  opener.add_handler(https_handler)

  response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

  return response

def fetchsamples():

  url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?
  track=money&locations"
  parameters = []
  response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)
  for line in response:
    print(line.strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fetchsamples()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the API doc: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter.html

`statuses/filter` uses POST, not GET.

For tweets around NYC use "locations=-74,40,-73,41". (You will need to expand this bounding box to make it 10 miles around NYC.) However, when used with `track` the two filters are OR'ed. In other words, you will get tweets that match either your `locations` filter or your `track` filter. You wont get only the tweets that match both filters.

EDIT

```
url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=money&locations=-74,40,-73,41"
parameters = []
response = twitterreq(url, "POST", parameters)
```

Comment: Jonas, thanks for the response. Could you tell me where I should make modifications in my code? Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. Is there a way to limit the radius of the search for a given pair of lats-longs?

Comment: The pair of latitudes and longitudes are two corners of a box. It's not a circle. See the link I included for specifics.